# how to get count of total records without size in elastic search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want to get count of total records from elastic search.
below is my code

```
 $params = [
            'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
            'type'  => $this->client->getType(),
            "from" => 0, "size" => 10,
            //"scroll" => "1m",

            'body'  => [
           "query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                              "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                              "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                              "query" => $query
                          ]
                     ],
                     [
                          "term"=> ["cat_type_id"=>1]
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
            ],
       ];
```

Executing manual query is giving 400 records whereas elastic search giving 10 records. How do I get total records regardless of size.?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be accessible trough:

```
$maxScore     = $results['hits']['max_score'];
```